# Configure Laravel 4 to send plain text errors for AJAX requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When my AJAX controllers fail, I normally get an HTML response back containing the stack info and error information. This is fine for normal controllers, as it gives us the prettier, more readable version.

However, for AJAX requests, I only want to see a plaintext version. Is there a way to configure Laravel to only send plain text / non-html errors on AJAX request errors?

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your `App::error()` filter:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::json( ['status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'There was an error. I could not find what you were looking for.'] );
    }

    return Response::view('errors.500', array(), 500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @josef.van.niekerk - if you have any further questions let me know, or please feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: Can you send the $exception back as plain text, and not the xdebug html version?

Comment: Found it! `$exception->getTraceAsString()`